# Are Square Connect's HTTP V1 and V2 endpoints compatible?

Tags: square-connect

Long story short: I attempted to create an order with the V2 endpoint, and then edit it with the V1 endpoint.

First, I created the order, and I got the following as a result:

```
{
"order": {
    "id": "OaL2MCgsn4gdBsemaz8wIFaxM2WMKLLDR7BwdeCl8T...",
"location_id": "8Q5T7REMOVED",
"reference_id": "my-order-001",
    (and so on)
    }
}
```

Then I attempted to close out the order with the following URL:

```
https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{{location_id}}/orders/OaL2MCgsn4gdBsemaz8wIFaxM2WMKLLDR7BwdeCl8Te...
```

But the reply was

```
{
    "type": "not_found",
    "message": "NotFound"
}
```

Since it's not finding the order I just made, I suspect that V1 and V2 endpoints aren't compatible. That, or my methodology is incorrect.

Are the square V1 and V2 endpoints compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, v1 and v2 endpoints are compatible. If you look up a transaction in [v1 Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#navsection-payments), you'll see the same info in [v2 Transactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-transactions).

The issue here is that `order` doesn't mean the same thing in the v1 and v2 worlds. In v1, orders are for Online Store orders, so when you try to [update an order](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#put-orderid), you are attempting to modify an order made with [Online Store](https://squareup.com/online-store) (`Updates the details of an online store order.`). Whereas the order you created with the [v2 endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-orders) was inteded to `Creates an Order that can then be referenced as order_id in a request to the Charge endpoint.`

If you are trying to modify an order that you will then send the id to the Charge endpoint, you cannot at this time and should instead just make a new order.